# Interpretation of Generalized Inverse Gaussian regression with GAMLSS

Tags: multiple-regression, mixture-distribution, generalized-additive-model, inverse-gaussian-distribution, gamlss

**Background on my project:**

I am comparing proteins (nodes) between a network representing protein interactions in metastatic patients v/s another network representing protein interactions in non-metastatic patients.

**What I want to do**

Briefly, I want to demonstrate that there is a correlation between the value of  a protein's characteristic ([Intrinsic Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsically_disordered_proteins)) and a  network difference parameter (e.g, the higher the Intrinsic Disorder of the protein is, the larger the difference in degree of this protein will be between metastatic and non-metastatic class).

I am looking at  building a simple model illustrating the relationship between my dependent variable (degree difference between metastatic and non-metastatic network) and a predictor variable (extent of intrinsic disorder in a given protein).

**What I have done**

I used the GAMLSS package in R to do a simple regression between my two parameters of interest. However I am unsure about how to go forward to interpret the coefficients and output of this particular regression w.r.t to the relationship between my variables.

**Output of my model**

[image: Output of my model]

**Question**

1)  I understand what the Mu  and sigma coefficient relates to the mean and standard deviation of my response,however,is there a  way to say  that for a unit change in my predictor variable, there is a change *x* in my dependent variable?